# Encrypt Deflate and encode to Base64 Xml

Tags: java, encoding, automation, base64, inflate

// XML needs to encrypt and deflate and encode using BASE64?I've used this code for this but I am not getting the exact output.

```
public String encryptDeflateAndBase64(String decryptedString) throws IOException {
        byte[] b=decryptedString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] c = new byte[550];
        Deflater compresser=new Deflater();
        compresser.setInput(b);
        compresser.finish();
        System.out.println(compresser.deflate(c));
        compresser.end();
        /*ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(decryptedString.length());
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        while (!compresser.finished()) {
            int count = compresser.deflate(buf);
            bos.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
        byte[] compressedData = bos.toByteArray();
*/       byte[] output = Base64.encodeBase64(c);
        return new String(output);
    }
```

Comment: What ("exact") output are you expecting? And why do you expect it (differently than actual)?  ..and I see no "encryption" in the code snippet, only (base64) "encoding".

Answer (score 2):

```
    //Remove: System.out.println(compresser.deflate(c));
    int count = compresser.deflate(c);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(c, 0, count);
    byte[] output = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bb);
```

Where I used the java.util.Base64. To not copy bytes, I used a ByteBuffer.